# Add a new blog entry in Docusaurus V2

Tags: docusaurus

I'm building a website with [Docusaurus V2](https://v2.docusaurus.io/).

There are already 3 blog entries in the initial project. I want to add another one. I created a file `4th.mdx` in the `blog` folder. Then added the following content:

```
---
id: 4th
title: Hello
author: Endilie Yacop Sucipto
authorTitle: Maintainer of Docusaurus
authorURL: https://github.com/endiliey
authorImageURL: https://avatars1.githubusercontent.com/u/17883920?s=460&v=4
authorTwitter: endiliey
tags: [hello, docusaurus]
---
```

Then, I guess I need to put the id `4th` somewhere in other files, right? Does anyone know where I should put that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Blog files are read from the `blog` directory and its `id` does not need to be added somewhere else. Are you not seeing the new entry even after creating the 4th file?